# Android AutocompleteTextView dropdown list adds padding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, dropdown, autocompletetextview

I have an `AutocompleteTextView` showing a custom layout for the items.

The items show correctly, but the problem is the list itself adds padding to the top and bottom. See image below. The red area is the list showing two items. The light gray at the top and bottom is the padding added by the list. The list item layout does not have this padding included. How do I set the padding or rather remove it for the dropdown list?

[image: AutocompompleteTextView dropdown list]

Here's my row file:

`row_user_suggestion.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:background="@color/sentRed"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="26dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="44dp"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/usernameTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fullnameTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The layout where dropdown is loaded:

`activity_layout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutForm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/title_send_transfer"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Large"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            style="@style/AppTheme.Spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorVeryLightGray"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteColorAccent">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/usernameTv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:dropDownHeight="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textColorLink="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteEditText" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/scanButton"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/scan_btn" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorVeryLightGray"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteColorAccent">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/messageTv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text|number|numberDecimal"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/white"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteEditText" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/nextButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:text="@string/next"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.PrimaryButton"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/form"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    />
```

I am using a custom adapter as mentioned, I don't think this is relevant here as I'm not setting any padding there, but adding for completeness:

`UserFilterAdapter.kt`

```
class UserFilterAdapter: ArrayAdapter<User>, Filterable {
private var mContext: Context? = null
private var mSuggestionList: List<User> = listOf()
private var mFilteredSuggestionList: List<User> = listOf()

constructor(context: Context, suggestionList: List<User>): super(context, R.layout.row_user_suggestion) {
    mContext = context
    mSuggestionList = suggestionList
    mFilteredSuggestionList = mSuggestionList
}

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    var view = convertView
    val viewHolder: ViewHolder
    if (view == null) {
        val inflater = mContext?.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_user_suggestion, null)
        viewHolder = ViewHolder()
        viewHolder.fullnameTv = view.findViewById(R.id.fullnameTv) as TextView
        viewHolder.usernameTv = view.findViewById(R.id.usernameTv) as TextView
        viewHolder.imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView) as ImageView
        view.setTag(viewHolder)
    } else {
        viewHolder = view.tag as ViewHolder
    }
    val searchSuggestion = mFilteredSuggestionList[position]
    viewHolder.usernameTv?.text = searchSuggestion.username
    viewHolder.fullnameTv?.text = searchSuggestion.name
    Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.avatar_placeholder_small).into(viewHolder.imageView)
    return view!!
}

fun setSuggestionList(list: List<User>) {
    mSuggestionList = list
    mFilteredSuggestionList = listOf()
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

class ViewHolder {
    var imageView: ImageView? = null
    var usernameTv: TextView? = null
    var fullnameTv: TextView? = null
}

override fun getCount(): Int {
    return mFilteredSuggestionList.size
}

override fun getItem(position: Int): User {
    val user = mFilteredSuggestionList[position]
    return user
}

override fun getFilter(): Filter {
    return object : Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
            val results = FilterResults()
            val constraintString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase()
            if (!constraintString.isEmpty()) {
                val tempFilteredList = mutableListOf<User>()
                for (suggestion in mSuggestionList) {
                    val name = suggestion.name
                    if (name.toLowerCase().contains(constraintString) ||
                            suggestion.username.toLowerCase().contains(constraintString)) {
                        tempFilteredList.add(suggestion)
                    }
                }
                results.values = tempFilteredList
                results.count = tempFilteredList.size
            } else {
                results.values = mSuggestionList
                results.count = mSuggestionList.size
            }
            return results
        }

        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults) {
            Log.d("FILTER", "Publishing results for $constraint: $results")
            if (results.values != null) {
                mFilteredSuggestionList = results.values as List<User>
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please edit and add the .xml where that list row is included?

Comment: Added the parent layout xml

Comment: Try specifying the parent to the inflater `view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_user_suggestion, parent, false)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom layout for your dropdown with results of filtering and define padding there. I have a bit more complex UI but take a look
My xml with `AutoCompleteTextView`

```
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteInput"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:dropDownAnchor="@id/registerInputParent"
        android:dropDownHeight="300dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:popupBackground="@drawable/rect_bottom_rounded_22_stroked_white"
        android:popupElevation="0dp"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_3dp_colored"
        tools:text="1,234.56" />
```

and my custom layout for popup rect_bottom_rounded_22_stroked_white.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Border -->
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners
                    android:bottomLeftRadius="22dp"
                    android:bottomRightRadius="22dp" />
                <solid android:color="@color/white" />
                <stroke
                    android:width="3.5dp"
                    android:color="@color/deep_lavender" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    <!-- Body -->
        <item
            android:bottom="3dp"
            android:left="3.5dp"
            android:right="3.5dp">
            <shape>
                <corners
                    android:bottomLeftRadius="22dp"
                    android:bottomRightRadius="22dp" />
                <solid android:color="@color/white" />
                <padding
                    android:bottom="10dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

I was need dropdown layout with rounded bottom corners and stroke on 3 sides
Your question was about line for custom layout

```
<padding
    android:bottom="10dp"/>
```